# Export from Couchbase to CSV file

Tags: csv, couchbase, nosql

I have a Couchbase Cluster with only one node (let's call it localhost) and I need to export all the data from a very big bucket (let's call it XXX) into a CSV file.

Now this seems to be a pretty easy task but I can't find the way to make it work.

According to the (really bad) documentation on the cbtransfer toold from Couchbase http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbtransfer_tool.html they say this is possible but they don't explain it clearly. They just add a flag if you want the transfer to occur in csv format (?) but it is not working. Maybe someone who already did this can give me a hand?

Using the documentation I've been able to make an approach to the result I want to obtain (a clean CSV file with all the documents in the XXX bucket) using this command:

**/opt/couchbase/bin/cbtransfer http://localhost:8091 /path/to/export/output.csv -b XXX**

But what I get is that /path/to/export/output.csv is actually a folder with a lot of folders inside and it is storing some kind of json metadata that can be used to restore the XXX bucket in another instance of Couchbase.

Has anyone been able to export data from a Couchbase bucket (Json documents) into a CSV file?

Comment: UPDATE: As @Kirk mentioned, you need to use csv: as a prefix in the command line but ALSO you need to specify a username and a password.  Even though the command was (not properly) working without those parameters, if I specify the username and password it finally exported all the documents as a flat CSV file. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From looking at the documentation, you have to put a slightly different syntax to export to a CSV. http://docs.couchbase.com/admin/admin/CLI/cbtransfer_tool.html

It needs to look like so:

cbtransfer http://[localhost]:8091 csv:./data.csv -b default -u Administrator -p password

Notice the "csv:" before the name of the csv file.

I tested this and it does export a CSV. Just be forwarned that you need a relatively flat document structure for this to work really well, as JSON can represent far more complex data structures than CSV obviously, e.g. arrays, sub-documents, etc. cbtransfer will not unravel those. For example, if there is a subdocument, cbtransfer will represent it as a JSON doc in the line of each CSV.

So depending on what your document structure is, exporting to CSV is not an ideal format. It is a step backwards.

Comment: The documents I need to export are actually very flat, just *key->values* and no subdocuments. I'll give this a shot but that whole "csv:" prefix is not documented. As I said that documentation in particular is very poor

Comment: How would you like me to change the documentation on the URL i posted. I can file a bug to get it changed perhaps.

Comment: The prefix csv: is something that isn't documented and is super important in my opinion. Also giving some more examples of import and export from/to couchbase using CSV files would be great. Also the use of -u and -p flags is underestimated in the official documentation

Comment: Not sure I follow. The example I gave you is straight from the documentation link I included in my answer.

Comment: The documentation may not be terribly helpful because Couchbase was not designed to export to CSV. It was designed to provide a very fast, highly-scalable, fault-tolerant, in-memory datastore. The fact that it can be made to export to CSV is a bonus :)  But you're in *terra nova* here. You also might be able to achieve this by using an index and running the conversion to CSV yourself client-side.